# laravel the comment page loaded dynamically does not work side jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, infinite-scroll

I have a page web post which contains comments, everything works very well with the implement infinite page scroll, except that the pages loaded dynamically the comment part does not work side jquery!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery `$(document).on()` like this

```
$(document).on(event, selector, function(){

     //implementation 

});
```

That should do the trick for you.

Jquery does not sees DOM objects loaded after document ready automatically

Comment: how can use jquery $(document).on()  on $('.desc').each(function() {....

Comment: I try with that $(document).on("each", ".desc",function(e) { .... but it does not work!

Comment: each is not an event to loop through `.desc`. You should use `$(".desc").each(function(i,v){ //... });`

Comment: also, I try with that $(".desc").each(function() { .... but it does not work!

Comment: what are you really trying to do

Comment: I try with $(".desc").each(function() {....